# Кроль как стиль плавания

Tags: этимология

Вот интересно, почему стиль плавания называется "кроль"? Я как-то не в курсе, как плавают кролики, но подозреваю, что все-таки не так, как люди-пловцы. Тогда почему же все-таки кроль?))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Кроль - это от английского *crawl*, буквально — ползание. Пловец кролем действительно как бы ползёт по воде, лёжа на ней животом.